# Cannot Remove Border in a Table

Tags: html, css

Please help, I can't figure out how to get rid of this border underline. It's nowhere to be found in Chrome's Inspect.  I've tried everything I could find in the forums but no luck so far.

I'm unable to reproduce it using a fiddle, but [here's](https://firsttestshop-2.myshopify.com/products/awesome-sneakers) the live site

[image]

HTML

```
<table class="table table-1" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th class="table-header cell-left">Actives</th>
    <th class="table-header cell-right">Percentage (%)</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="table-data cell-left">Caster Oil</td>
    <td class="table-data cell-right">25</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="table-data cell-left">Peppermint Oil</td>
    <td class="table-data cell-right">0.5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="table-data cell-left">Cinnamon Oil</td>
    <td class="table-data cell-right">0.25</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.table {
  color: $Blue;
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
th {
  font-family: 'PPsans', Fallback, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
td {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.cell-right {text-align:right;}
.cell-left {text-align: left;}
```

Comment: Provide a working example. The current code doesn't have any border.

Comment: I don't know how... this is the code I'm using and that's what I see in the browser.

Comment: This is not the entire code, obviously. Open a jsfiddle and put all the code there.

Comment: Make sure that you can see the border, otherwise it will be impossible to help.

Comment: Thanks, I just updated with a link to a live site.  I tried reproducing it in a fiddle, but there's no problem there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `tr:first-child th:after, tr:first-child td:after` with `border-bottom: 1px solid #1c1d1d;` which creates that border.

You can override this using:

```
tr:first-child th:after, tr:first-child td:after {
    border: none;
}
```

Make sure this goes **after** the previous code (or edit the original css file).

Answer (score 0):

```
tr:first-child th:after, tr:first-child td:after{
border-bottom: none !important; 
}
```

if you have custom css file then use !important